# Convert dataframe to dict?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following data structure (called `df`):

```
    x         Fx          Fxcum
0  -1.192809  0.888734    0.888734
1  -1.182809  0.483803    1.372537
2  -1.172809 -0.318153    1.054384
3  -1.162809 -0.966345    0.088038
4  -1.152809 -1.512387   -1.424349
```

The titles `x`, `Fx`, and `Fxcum` are dynamic. If I apply the function `tolist()`:

```
dict(y=df['x'].tolist())
```

I get:

```
{'x': [-1.192809,
       -1.182809,
       -1.172809,
       -1.162809,
       -1.152809]}
```

First of all I need to read the titles that are not always `x`, `Fx`, and `Fxcum` and get the following list:

```
{'x': [-1.192809,
       -1.182809,
       -1.172809,
       -1.162809,
       -1.152809],
 'Fx': [-1.192809,
       -1.182809,
       -1.172809,
       -1.162809,
       -1.152809],
 'Fxcum': [-1.192809,
       -1.182809,
       -1.172809,
       -1.162809,
       -1.152809]}
```

Can you point me in the right direction. Do I need to create a loop or are there some libraries that can help me out?

Comment: I take it with df you're using python pandas?  And you want to convert all columns `x`, `fx`, or `fxcum`?

Comment: if this is a pandas DataFrame, just do `df.to_dict()`. You can mess around with the `orient` parameter to get it in the form that you want.

Comment: Hi Tony, yes I am using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it seems like you are using Pandas.

Pandas has a method for doing exactly what you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

`df.to_dict('list')`

Example:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
a     1   0.1
b     2   0.2
>>> df.to_dict('list')
{'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [0.5, 0.75]}
```

Comment: `.to_dict(orient="list")` should return the values like they want.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that!